# Delete multiple entities at once using Azure Table Storage Node.js interface

Tags: node.js, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

The only delete operation I get deletes one at a time: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/table-services/#delete-entity

What I want is equivalent to the SQL statement

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE PartitionKey = 'something'
```

Also on that page is a way to send a batch (although I could not get this to work with delete, anyone know why?). However, I'd first have to do a select to get the list of entities I want to delete in order to get their RowKeys. I was wondering whether it's possible to do it in only one request to Azure.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Here's the code I tried and it doesn't work. I have confirmed that all arguments are correct when the function is called.

```
// subAccts all have PartitionKey = pKey
function deleteAccount(pKey, rKey, subAccts, callback) {
  var tasks = subAccts; // rename for readability
  tasks.push({ PartitionKey: pKey, RowKey: rKey });
  tableService.beginBatch();
  async.forEach(tasks, function(task, callback) {
    tableService.deleteEntity(myTable, task, function(error) {
      if (!error) {
        callback(null);
      }
      else {
        console.log(error);
        callback(error);
      }
    });
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      callback(error);
      return;
    }
    tableService.commitBatch(callback);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can't delete the entities without knowing which entities you want to delete. That doesn't mean you have to fetch them first. Could you explain more about the problem you're having?

Comment: I want to delete every entity with a given `PartitionKey` in the most efficient way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the list of entities you want to delete in advance, you'll have to query first to find them.

You might consider restructuring your table, though. If, instead of just putting these entities in the same partition, you could put them all in the same table (by themselves), you could delete the table. This is commonly used for deleting old logs... create tables like log_january, log_february, and then you can just delete an entire month at a time with a single command.

**EDIT**

There appears to be a bug in the library. Try this edit as a workaround:

```
BatchServiceClient.prototype.addOperation = function (webResource, outputData) {
    if (azureutil.objectIsNull(outputData)) {
        outputData = '';
    }

    if (webResource.httpVerb !== 'GET') {
        webResource.headers[HeaderConstants.CONTENT_ID] = this.operations.length + 1;

        if (webResource.httpVerb !== 'DELETE') {
            webResource.headers[HeaderConstants.CONTENT_TYPE] = 'application/atom+xml;type=entry';
        } else {
            delete webResource.headers[HeaderConstants.CONTENT_TYPE];
        }
...
```

I've created a pull request to fix this in the dev branch: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/pull/300.

Until this is fixed, you can always clone my fork (https://github.com/smarx/azure-sdk-for-node), checkout the `dev` branch, and `npm install` that, rather than hand-editing the code.

Comment: Okay, so I'll query them first, and now I have an array of `{PartitionKey, RowKey}` objects. Using that, I tried the batch method on the page I linked to, but it didn't work. I changed `insertEntity` to `deleteEntity`, but that's the only change I made. Does their code look wrong? I can confirm that `deleteEntity` gets called for each task and `commitBatch` is called at the end, but nothing happens.

Comment: That all looks about right. Have you captured the HTTP traffic (with Fiddler or the like) to see what's going on? Is the HTTP request being sent? What's the response?

Comment: Well, I see the request that causes the above code to be called, and I see that it correctly results in a 204 code. However, I don't see the actual HTTP request to Azure that I would have expected `commitBatch` to cause. I then noticed that even when I do individual requests per delete (which does work, but slowly), I still don't see any HTTP requests to Azure.

Comment: For `deleteEntity` batches, it shouldn't matter if I have additional (user-defined) fields, should it? Like if I delete `{ PartitionKey: 'p1', RowKey: '1', Desc: 'foo' }` it should still be fine? I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be, but right now I'm desperate enough to consider anything.

Comment: I would think it wouldn't matter, but you could check the code.

Comment: I found a bug (actually a couple) in the Node storage library... I'll edit my answer, and I'll get a bug filed.

Comment: Hmm, even adding the else-block you provided didn't do it. EDIT: Oh wait, yes it did, I needed to change the constants to 'GET' and 'DELETE' as well. Thanks!